# C# Pass values from form 1 to form 2

Tags: c#

I'm having 2 different Form elements inside my Winforms application. Now I'm trying to pass some variables from Form 1 to Form 2 by running the following code:

```
async void bunifuFlatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please get the authentification Pin before continuing.", "Twitter Buddy error");
    }
    else
    {
        await pinAuth.CompleteAuthorizeAsync(bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text);
        SharedState.Authorizer = pinAuth;

        var credentials = pinAuth.CredentialStore;

        if (credentials != null)
        {
            string oauthToken = credentials.OAuthToken;
            string oauthTokenSecret = credentials.OAuthTokenSecret;
            string screenName = credentials.ScreenName;
            ulong userID = credentials.UserID;

            new Form1(oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret, screenName, userID).Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please authorize this application before continuing.", "Twitter Buddy error");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to accept the values in the second form like this:

```
public Form1(string oauthToken, string oauthTokenSecret, string screenName, ulong userID)
{
    string OauthToken = oauthToken;
    string OauthTokenSecret = oauthTokenSecret;
    string ScreenName = screenName;
    ulong UserID = userID;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

But somehow Form 2 does not let me use those values. Been testing the following:

```
MessageBox.Show(this.OauthToken);
```

and received the following error message:

```
Error CS1061 'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'OauthToken' and no extension method 'OauthToken' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Does anyone have a idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the declaration of the variables out. Now the scope of the variables is limited to the constructor only. Read more about the scope of variables [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132.aspx).

```
string OauthToken;
string OauthTokenSecret;
string ScreenName;
ulong UserID;

public Form1(string oauthToken, string oauthTokenSecret, string screenName, ulong userID)
{
    this.OauthToken = oauthToken;
    this.OauthTokenSecret = oauthTokenSecret;
    this.ScreenName = screenName;
    this.UserID = userID;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```